# How to let direct traffic visit my site

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

I'm using this code in my htaccess file to only allow people that are referred from the domain of our choosing to visit our site. However, is there a way we can allow people that type in our domain, to access the site as well? (but block all other referrers?)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://the-ok-domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://your-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://the-website-of-your-choosing.com/ [L,R]
```

Comment: This strategy is flawed, actually. The HTTP_REFERER is provided by the browser and thus not reliable. It should never be used for anything as important as "only allowing certain people".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, is there a way we can allow people that type in our domain, to access the site as well? (but block all other referrers?)

Add a blank referer check:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://the-ok-domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://your-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://the-website-of-your-choosing.com/ [L,R]
```

Also note that referers can be easily forged, so there's no guarantee that this will be effect in preventing people from linking to your site.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect for our needs!

Comment: Also, would I be able to add extra referrer domains? Like this:


`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://the-ok-domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://yahoo.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://gmail.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://your-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://the-website-of-your-choosing.com/ [L,R]`

Comment: @user1446650 yes, they're all *and*ed together so you can add as many as you need